# How to make data in a table unable to be used (i.e. disallow to perform query on it)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables in a database, `users` and `users_removed` with columns "id(primary key), email(unique), password" and "id, user_id(foreign key (user_id) references users(id)" respectively.

When a user registers the `users` table gets the data accordingly. And when the user wants to delete account I can get user's id in `users_removed` and consider it deleted such as

```
INSERT into users_removed (user_id) 
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = 'user@example.com'))
```

The `id` from `users` gets inserted into `users_removed` with a foreign key constraint.

Now the question is what will be the right way to get rid of data from `users` with that `id` but preserve it somehow.

1. Deleting entirely is not an option because I loose data and so the purpose of the table `users_removed`. Also if I delete I get error "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails" because of the foreign key constraint.
2. The user should be able to re-register with previous email but considering it an entirely new entry, as `email` in `users` is unique.

Is there a way in sql to make certain data unable to be used, disallow to perform query on it, such as it gets ignored when I perform query in the backend.

Or what could be the possible ways to the solution?

I have a way of restricting `users_removed` to be able to login, but how should I proceed with the registration thing.

Comment: Make a AFTER INSERT TRIGGER

Comment: Item 2 seems like self contradiction, since you cannot have an entirely new entry which has a primary key value which is the same as an existing entry.  As for final question, the standard method is to create a view which filters out tge rows you want to ignore, and only allow users to query that view instead of the original tables.

Answer (score 0):

As mysql doesn't allow rerecly to use a select in the INSERT and delete from the same table, you must corcumvent ideally in a programming language out side of mysql.

I used here a seperate SELCT with a user defined variable, to get first the user_id

```
CREATE TABLE users (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key, email varchar(100) UNIQUE)
```

```
CREATE TABLE  users_removed (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key,user_id int)
```

```
INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES ('user@example.com')
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_users_removed_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON users_removed FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = new.user_id;
    END IF;
END
```

```
SELECT id INTO @user_id FROM users WHERE email = 'user@example.com'  ;
INSERT into users_removed (user_id) 
VALUES (@user_id)
```

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

| id | email |
| --- | --- |

```
INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES ('user@example.com')
```

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | user@example.com |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fwvstmgf)

Comment: It won't let "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = new.user_id;" if "user_id" has a foreign key constraint in code sample #04.

Comment: the foreign key makes no sense at all, you can only reference existing rows, but you try to delete the one in users , so remove the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it will better to add two fields (IsDeleted, DeletedAt) to the users table.

```
CREATE TABLE usersss (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  email varchar(100),
  IsDeleted tinyInt default 0,
  DeletedAt datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY uk_email (email, IsDeleted),
  KEY email (email),
  KEY IsDeleted (IsDeleted)
);
```

You will include (IsDeleted=0) within your conditions in every query that deals with users.

when the user wants to delete account, You will set IsDeleted to 1 and DeletedAt to NOW().

```
UPDATE users SET IsDeleted=1 AND DeletedAt = NOW() WHERE id=$ID;
```

To make user able to re-register with previous email you will check for a unique index on fields (email, IsDeleted) not on (email).

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE (IsDeleted=0) AND (email = '$email');
```

If query returns (0) then the user can use that email.
you may remove the data of users with IsDeleted=1 after a specified period of time has elapsed from the date of deletion (DeletedAt).
Example :
If you want to remove user and its data after one year, to get users you will remove :

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) >= (TO_DAYS(DeletedAt) + 365) ;
```

then you will delete data from related tables for these users.

Comment: But it still won't let re-register with same email, returns "Duplicate entry 'user@example.com' for key 'email'", I ended up concatenating users email with a delete flag upon account deletion so their same original email can be used to re-register.

Comment: @first Don't use `UNIQUE KEY` for field email. Use `KEY` only. I edited the answer and added a key for `email` field.